# jQuery Nested Sortable - Copying rather than moving items between 2 lists

Tags: jquery, nested, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I am using an app where you drag and drop list items between 2 nested sortables: http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/Ge7eK/9/

My question is how would you change the code so it copied elements from one list to the other, rather than move them? Seems like a simple change but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten it most of the way there:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ge7eK/41/

```
receive: function(event, ui){
    var ele = document.elementFromPoint(ui.position.left, ui.position.top);
    var newEle = ui.item.clone();        
    newEle.attr("id", ""); // trying to prevent duplicate ids
    $(ele).after(newEle);            
},

remove: function(event, ui){
    event.preventDefault(); // this stops the item from being removed
}
```

There's a bug happening when you drag an item from, say list A to list B, then drag another item from list A over that copied item. I'm not sure why it is happening, but it may have something to do with the ids you're using.

Also, the drop position can be a little bit finicky. If your placeholder item is between two items in the list (instead of overlapping one slightly), it will add that item to the end of the list.

Comment: I should note that I'm using `elementFromPoint` because I couldn't find the insert point that the sortable plugin is using in the available callback arguments.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That seems to work nicely for making sure the from element is copied, not moved. I am trying to figure out the drop bug as well but this is much appreciated.

Comment: @JeffFuller I would suggest not declaring ids in that pattern unless it's completely necessary.